# Which forces does work on a conical pendulum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, free-body-diagram

This is a question in my testbook and a site that I use for solutions says that the answer is tension force. But I think that the work done should be zero. However I might miss out on something. So what is the answer?

Comment: The direction of the tension force is at right angles to motion of the bob.  No work is done by the tension force or the gravitational force.

Comment: The motion is persistant because no energy is used - i.e. no work is done. Of course that's an ideal case, a practical penulum experiences losses of energy due to work done against air resistance and deformation of the suspension mechanism/string etc.

Answer (score 1):

In a real conical pendulum, you will see a gradual decay of the amplitude of motion due to drag. Consequently, there are two forces that do work:

1. drag (negative work)
2. gravity (as the anplitude decreases, some gravitational potential turns to kinetic energy)

Both of these forces have a component in the direction of motion. Tension is always perpendicular to the direction of motion - so it can not do work.